# Which logs and command line tools for finding processes that hog the macOS CPU?

Tags: macos, command-line, performance, cpu

As you can see, I have frequent CPU hogs:
[image]

I inspected my mac with several security tools from https://objective-see.org/tools.html, if any viruses or shady processes are being started up or running in the background. This is not the case as far I can see.

What command line tools and/or logs can I use to find out where these loads on the CPU originate?

Answer (score 3):

The best tool for determining which processes are using CPU are the graphical activity monitor you have up and the `top` command.

Start with `top -u -s 60` and see if you like longer intervals than 60 seconds or shorter intervals. You can press the space bar anytime to get a refresh if you see a spike in the graph and you'll have some time to examine all the top users of CPU until the next refresh of the calculations.

I'm not sure there's any log file that will help you with this, but one or two top sessions should get you more details on what the processor is doing when it's "busy". The graph there looks perfectly normal and 77% idle is a very nice stat to see.

Here's my Mac idling along this morning:

[image: 95% idle macOS with light web browsing]

And after I start Maps, Photos, Calendar a small jump that goes back to idle rapidly.

[image: Small CPU usage spike opening a few well behaved apps on macOS]

[image: macOS idling again after app launch and CPU usage]

Comment: Thanks, I am trying out the command. Please note that the 77% idle time was after the peak

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `top` and Activity Monitor, you can see select historic performance related logs via the Console application.

## Console

The included **Console.app** on macOS includes a **Diagnostic Reports** section. These are logs created when an unexpected event occurs or a resource threshold is exceeded.

- /Applications/Utilities/Console.app

The log files are stored on your Mac at:

- /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

These reports include unexpected behaviour by individual command line tools.

See [View reports in Console on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/console/cnsl664be99a/mac) for Apple's documentation:

> ### View reports in Console on Mac
>
> Console compiles various reports that provide general diagnostic data, as well as details about your computer’s operating system and apps. You can access the following reports from the sidebar:
>
> - Crash Reports: System and user reports about apps or processes that crash. Crash report names have the .ips extension.
> - Spin Reports: System and user reports with details about app or process issues. Spin report names have a .spin extension.
> - Log Reports: System and user reports with information about events that occur when the system or specific apps are processing. Log report names have an extension such as .log, ._log or .its.
> - **Diagnostic Reports**: System and user reports with information about hardware resources, system response times and more. Diagnostic report names have an extension such as .diag or .dpsub.
> - ...

Comment: Great points! Spins, crashes and hangs don’t always soak CPU. Are there any specifics in the logs relating to usage you’ve found are useful for after the fact analysis ?

Comment: also very interested if the logs can be used to get towards past CPU hogs. Bmike's answer is great if its reproducible, but at the moment my Mac is not having the CPU hogs as frequently.